# Unable to use group by

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join

I'm trying to solve the challenge but I tried couple of ways to make my logic work, but I'm unable to understand why does my group by function doesn't work here. Any help on this greatly appreciated and please let me know if the below information is not good enough. Here is link for the challenge and below is my code.

```
select count(sub.hacker_id), hacker.name from submissions sub 
inner join challenges challenge on challenge.challenge_id=sub.challenge_id 
inner join difficulty difficult on difficult.difficulty_level = 
challenge.difficulty_level and difficult.score = sub.score
inner join hackers hacker on hacker.hacker_id = sub.hacker_id 
group by hacker.hacker_id 
order by sub.hacker_id desc ;
```

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/full-score/problem

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the selected columns that are not arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY hacker.name`.

Comment: Please add your desired behaviour and _why_ your solution is not working

Comment: @jarlh when I try that, this is the error I get. ERROR 1055 (42000) at line 5: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'run_p5l7kzzu0te.sub.hacker_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Oops, missed the ORDER BY. The rule is: When GROUP BY, SELECT DISTINCT, and UNION, only select list items may be in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `HAVING` condition to your query:

```
SELECT h.hacker_id, h.name
FROM Submissions s
INNER JOIN Challenges c
    ON s.challenge_id = c.challenge_id 
INNER JOIN Difficulty d
    ON c.difficulty_level = d.difficulty_level
INNER JOIN Hackers h
    ON s.hacker_id = h.hacker_id 
WHERE d.score = s.score
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, h.hacker_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Lamak. Can you give me the logic as why we need use count(*) in the bottom and not on the top. From what I understand on how group by function works is that, you need to basically use agreegate in the query first and then use group by in the bottom of the query which will do the aggregation for you similar to distinct function. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I didn't add the `COUNT(*)` to the `SELECT` because the requirement is to return the hacker_id and name. I did add a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, because you want the hackers with more than 1 perfect score

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a variable sql_mode before your query.

```
SET sql_mode = "";
```

This should work for you!